# Nodejs - Cannot set property of undefined sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, parse-platform

I am using express 3 framework for nodejs. I am trying to setup sessions, this is my code

```
var express = require('express');

    var app = express();
    var parseExpressCookieSession = require('parse-express-cookie-session');
    var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(parseExpressCookieSession({
        secret: "The very sweet secret"
    }));
    app.use(app.router);


    app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
        req.session.uid = "dssss"
        console.log(req.session.uid);
        res.render('login', {
            title: 'Login'
        });
    })
```

I get the error saying cannot set property of 'uid' of undefined. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: try using this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Answer (score 1):

You can add express-session module and seen here: https://github.com/expressjs/session

From the docs:

> req.session
>
> To store or access session data, simply use the request property
>   req.session, which is (generally) serialized as JSON by the store, so
>   nested objects are typically fine. For example below is a
>   user-specific view counter:

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var sess = req.session
  if (sess.views) {
    sess.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (sess.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    sess.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```